# how to clear keyboard background color in iOS 8?

Tags: ios

I would like to know how to change the keyboard background color programmatically in iOS? The background is normally grey but I need clear background color (behind letters).

Comment: I'm afraid all keyboard styles are predefined in `UIKeyboardAppearance` enum

Answer (score 2):

There are no direct properties which would let you do that. One option is to create a custom [inputView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView)

Another is to get all the views from the key window, find the view for the keyboard and make changes. But this is not advisable and can break at any point.